# Got "Run-time error '13': Type mismatch" when trying to detect if a Userform is closed - in Excel VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on an Excel macro, where at some point of time I need to determine if a userform instance is already closed/unloaded or not.

I would like to do so by only dealing with the userform variable, not by adding code at the form_queryclose event handler. The reason of that is that the userform is created by other workbooks, and that AFAIK I have no way to know the time of a userform being created.

Until now, what I only get is the following error (leaving me scratching my head hard):

```
Run-time error '13': Type mismatch
```

Here's how to reproduce the error (I'm using MS Excel 2010 Pro Plus 32 bit):

- Create a workbook and open VBA IDE as usual. Create a userform,
  leaving the default name as "UserForm1"
- Create a module and paste in the following lines:

  ```
  Option Explicit

  Dim f As UserForm1

  Sub proc1()
      Set f = New UserForm1
      f.Show 0

  End Sub

  Sub proc2()
      If Not IsFormLoaded(f) Then    ' <---- Error
          MsgBox "form is unloaded already!"
          Exit Sub
      End If
      MsgBox f.Caption
  End Sub
  Function IsFormLoaded(f As Variant) As Boolean
      If f Is Nothing Then Exit Function

      If Not TypeOf f Is UserForm Then Err.Raise -1, , "Parameter is not a user form!"
      Dim errnum As Long, v
  On Error GoTo er
      v = f.Caption
  er:
      errnum = Err.Number
  On Error GoTo 0
      IsFormLoaded = errnum = 0
  End Function
  ```
- Place caret at proc1 and press F5 to execute it. A form pops up. Immediately close it.
- Place caret at proc2 and press F5... Boom

IsFormLoaded is the function and is the point of me raising this question you are reading. It is to avoid accessing the userform's member variables when the userform COM object is in an invalid state.

If you bother to step through the code you will find that the cursor will go through the lines of IsFormLoaded happily like normal, but the point of error will be at the 1st line of proc2() (If Not IsFormLoaded(f) then).

I just want IsFormLoaded to work, and if there are workarounds it will be great, but using VBA.Userforms to check the availability is out of the question as the userforms belong to other workbooks and will not be found in VBA.Userforms.

Comment: Change the declaration to `Function IsFormLoaded(ByVal f As Variant) As Boolean`

Comment: @Rory Make that an answer since it works.

Comment: Works perfectly, thanks! You can post it as a reply so that I can mark it as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the declaration to `Function IsFormLoaded(ByVal f As Variant) As Boolean`